# Calculus 2 integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

So I'm currently doing calc 2 and we have this relatively weird concept of "Partition" or "Division", not sure what's the correct term in English. Nevertheless, I'm struggling with it. Here's an example question with this particular concept.

Let $f: [0, 4] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  &  0 \leq x < 1 \\
x,  &  1 \leq x < 3 \\
4,  &  x = 3 \\
5, & 3 < x \leq 4
\end{cases}$$

and let $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ be the "Partition" of $[0, 4]$ called $P$

1. Compute the difference of the upper and lower sum $\bar{S}_{P}(f)$ $-$ $\underline{S}_{P}(f)$

Even the notation here is a bit sketchy. Could someone elaborate on this a bit? I think it has something to do with Riemann sums.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Apologies for that. Unfortunately, the problem here was that I actually have no idea what's the correct topic for this particular concept so I would only be misguiding people and therefore went with the general. @Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a partition $P:x_0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$ we define the upper riemann sum as
$$\bar{S}_P(f)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\max_{x\in [x_k,x_{k+1}]}f(x) \cdot(x_{k+1}-x_k)$$
and the lower riemann sum as
$$\underline{S}_P(f)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\min_{x\in [x_k,x_{k+1}]}f(x) \cdot(x_{k+1}-x_k)$$
Notice that if $f$ is positive, then $\bar{S}_P(f)$ will be a sum of areas of rectangles, that are above the graph, and $\underline{S}_P(f)$ a sum of areas of rectangles under the graph, so intutively we should have $$\underline{S}_P(f) \leq \int_{x_0}^{x_n}f(x)dx \leq \bar{S}_P(f)$$
In your example we get
$$\bar{S}_P(f)=\sum_{k=0}^{3}\max_{x\in [k,k+1]}f(x) \cdot(k+1-k)=1+2+4+5 = 12$$
and
$$\underline{S}_P(f)=\sum_{k=0}^{3}\min_{x\in [k,k+1]}f(x) \cdot(k+1-k)=1+1+2+4=8$$

Comment: Quite often i see this $\bar{S}_P(f)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Delta x \cdot M_{k}$ represented as the upper sum. How does this differ from the one you proposed?

Comment: The difference is only the notation. $\Delta x$ is the difference in $x$-values, which is $\Delta x = x_k-x_{k-1}$. And $M_k$ would be the maximum value that $f$ takes on the interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$.

Comment: Intuitively speaking, shouldn't it be $\bar{S}_P(f)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Delta x \cdot f(x_{k})$? Since $\Delta x$ denotes the width of the rectangles and $f(x_{k})$ would be denoting the height of the rectangle at $k$? Perhaps I'm confused with the idea of taking the maximum.

Comment: $x_k$ is the right end point of $[x_{k-1},x_k]$, therefore $\sum_{k=1}^n \Delta x\cdot f(x_k)$ is called a right riemann sum and similarly $\sum_{k=1}^n \Delta x\cdot f(x_{k-1})$ is a left riemann sum. I guess the easiest way to understand it is through some pictures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#/media/File:Riemann_sum_convergence.png here is a left, right, upper and lower sum (see if you can spot which is what :-) ). The importance of lower and upper sums are that they always give a lower/upper bound for the actual integral.

Comment: Also see if you can verify the following statements:

1) If $f$ is increasing, then a right sum is an upper sum and a left sum is a lower sum.

2) If $f$ is decreasing, then a left sum is an upper sum and a right sum is a lower sum.